# Upload image to Twitter with REST API

Tags: rest, twitter

I am trying to upload an image to Twitter and make it appear automatically, meaning not needing to click "Show Photo".  I am able to  post a status and image using POST statuses/update_with_media.  That is fairly easy to do, but it still does not appear "inline."  The [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media-multiple-photos) shows an example of uploading an image with twurl but I am working on Windows.  Does anyone have an example with jQuery or a REST client showing how to us the https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json service?  I tried putting the parameters in the url and the body but each time I get Bad Request.

[image: Example]

Comment: please post your answer as an answer instead of an edit to the question.

Comment: That seems reasonable.  Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I spend about 15 hours working on this, I found a "solution" 10 minutes after posting on SO. It seems that the size of the image plays a role. I just used statuses/update_with_media using a larger image and it appeared inline. A slightly smaller image does not appear inline. I would still like to know how to call the service though.